# Create animation on non UI thread

Tags: wpf, asynchronous

I am having a bit of a problem with a WPF application. The application loads from a database and then creates a bunch of own made Usercontrols. When I load lets say 1000 of these Usercontrols the UI thread blocks. Now I have tried multiple things with loading the Usercontrols on a different thread and then adding them to the main thread, but that is simply not possible I found out (or somebody must have a proper working example).

Is it possible to create a thread with a loading animation that is not blocking while the main UI thread is doing things?

Comment: Are you looking for an animated splash screen at startup, or something else?

Comment: Could you post some (pseudo)code of what you are doing. Having interactive ui during processing is possible, but maybe not the way you tried....

Comment: By design only the main thread can interact with the UI.  I suspect you could create the UI object in the background and then place on the Page/Window in the main thread but I suspect that will not buy you much.  You might get some relief by putting the UI controls in a collection and then binding the collection to the UI if you UI design is ameabable to that.   Are all these control animating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform most of work in the thread that loads data from database and use Dispatcher class
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx
to perform the UI related operations on the main thread.